# Navigation Controller resizing only works in portrati?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on an app that has a navigation view controller in a view controller. Everything works fine except for the fact that when it dosen't start in portrait the navigation controller isn't properly sized and takes up the whole screen. I have screenshots how what is happening.

here is what happens when application is started in portrait [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/64978867@N06/5954097072/in/set-72157627106498273/)

now when the application starts in either landscape right/left or portrait upside down this happen [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/64978867@N06/5953540893/in/set-72157627106498273/)

I don't know if anyone has a solution for this problem since because it has a space at the top there is always a gap when the rotation occurs.

For more reference i've included some of my code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
SongsViewController *viewController = [[SongsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SongsViewController" bundle:nil];

dataView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[dataView setDelegate:self];
dataView.view.frame = CGRectMake(192, 85, 768 - 192, 1004 - 85 - 44);
[dataView.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[dataView.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];

[self.view addSubview:dataView.view];
[viewController release];
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation ==       UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    dataView.view.frame = CGRectMake(192, 85, 768 - 192, 1004 - 85 - 44);

}

else {

    dataView.view.frame = CGRectMake(192, 85, 1024 - 192, 748 - 85 - 44);

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you ideally shouldnt be adding a ViewController's view as a subview to another viewController's view. Atleast in iOS <= 4.3.

What you must be doing is start your application with the ViewController's view embedded inside a navigationController. What I mean to say is, try to make the root view controller of your application as navigationController. Or, if you have a tabBar as the base of your application, try making each tab's viewController as navigationController.

Next, use the viewController's property:

```
self.navigationController
```

To further push / pop viewControllers into or from it.

You need not do those frame adjustments in the rotation delegate methods, all you have to do is set the autoresizing masks properly for the view components (subviews of) of your SongsViewController and rest all should be taken care automatically.

Comment: Will look into the autoresizing masked from the subviews. I know that the navigation controller inside of a view controller is unconventional but I need it to be able to move through list on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Using a different rotation function seemed to fix the problem.
I used:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```